# How to add onkeypress save in php form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**This is my php `index.php` file. I want to type first name and last name type and auto it has to be save the database. I wrote the code using ajax. but, this is not working properly. Please can any one help me. **

**index.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
$db = mysql_select_db("type", $connection); 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

if($firstName !=''||$lastName !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("insert into users(firstName, lastName) values ('$firstName', '$lastName')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta><title>Home Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('keyup','firstName','lastName',function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        var flatvalue = $(this).val();
        $("#firstName"+rel).val(flatvalue);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post"> 
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" ><br><br>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" ><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are two ways to post your data. 1) Submit Form using jQuery on onKeyUp event. 2) Post data to Ajax file and save your data.

Comment: please can you give me help

Comment: do you mean you want to save the changes on your text box on every press made?

Comment: @perseusl, yes, when I type something on the text box. it want to save on DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onKeyPress event not proper because it call many times as per user hit.

Use onBlur event instead of onKeyPress for submit the form and save it to MySql users table.

Try below example,

PHP

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "jaydeep_mor", "jaydeep_mor"); 
$db = mysql_select_db("jaydeep_mor", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName'])){
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

    if($firstName != '' || $lastName != ''){
        //Insert Query of SQL
        $query = mysql_query("insert into users(firstName, lastName) values ('$firstName', '$lastName')");
        header("Location: test.php?msg=Data Inserted successfully...!!");
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

HTML / JAVASCRIPT

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta><title>Home Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveData(){
        document.forms["userDataForm"].submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && trim($_GET['msg'])!=""){ ?>
        <br /><div><?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?></div><br />
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" name="userDataForm"> 
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['firstName'])?$_POST['firstName']:''; ?>" ><br><br>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['lastName'])?$_POST['lastName']:''; ?>" onblur="return saveData();" ><br><br>
        <!--input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="submit"/-->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the answer. thank you my friend. Now I want customize it.

Comment: Welcome always @loke2.

Comment: `Data Inserted successfully...!!` this message how to show `index.php`

Comment: Set header("Location: index.php?msg=Data Inserted successfully...!!"); and add below div to index.php. <?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && trim($_GET['msg'])!=""){ ?>
        <br /><div><?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?></div><br />
    <?php } ?>

Comment: this is you already added my friend. but i will showing message on URL

Comment: If showing message in URL you can get using $_GET['msg'] method and echoing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
$db = mysql_select_db("type", $connection); 
if(isset($_REQUEST['firstName'])){
$firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];

 if($firstName !=''||$lastName !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("insert into users(firstName, lastName) values ('$firstName', '$lastName')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>"; 
die();
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
die();

}
}
//mysql_close($connection);
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta><title>Home Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#submit').click(function(){ alert('d');
        var firstname = $('#firstName').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastName').val();
       $.ajax({
           url:'',
           data:{'firstname':firstname,'lastname':lastname, },
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data){
              alert("Data Save: " + data);
         }
          });
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"><br><br>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try doing it this way

```
$('body').delegate('input[type="text"]', 'keypress keydown keyup change propertychange paste', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    if (event.type === 'keydown' || event.type === 'keypress') {
        return;
    }
    //insert what you want to do here
    //perform some ajax
    /*
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'firstName' : $('input[name=firstName]).val(),
            'lastName' : $('input[name=lastName]).val()
        },
        success: function(mResponse) {
            alert(mResponse);
        }
    });
    */
});
```

Comment: Data will save using ajax, But, I want how to use onkeypress save the data my friend. Please can you help me.

Comment: what do you mean on key press? the code i provided will save it on key press.

Comment: When I'm typing it want to save in database. before click on the `submit` button

Comment: So you want to save it on clicking submit? or you want it to save as the user presses any key?

Comment: i wan to save as the user presses any key

Comment: that's what my provided answer does o.O just uncomment the ajax part and fix the code that will suffice your need

Comment: if you can see on the code, 
`if (event.type === 'keydown' || event.type === 'keypress') {`

I've added this to avoid spam on your database when user press and hold a  certain key. It will only save once user releases the key

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help  you,
if you want to do it via form submit then just you need to give the url of your controller function in the action method of the form

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" ><br><br>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

if you want to do it via ajax then you can add id attribute for first_name and last_name input and can do it in following way,

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
$.ajax({
        url: url of your controler, //url of your controller function
        type: "POST",
        data: {'first_name' : first_name,'last_name':last_name},
                    success: function (data) {

                        //whatever you want to do on success

                        } else {
                            //in case of no data 
                        }
                    }

                });
```

});

in the same way you can give a class attribute to the input box and on `keyup event` can save the data via class

Comment: Data will save using ajax, But, I want how to use onkeypress save the data my friend. Please can you help me.

Comment: What I have done with clik event you can do it with keypress event assigning a class attribute for your input box and as I have attached click event with id, you can do it with class $(".classname"). on('keypress', function (){})

Comment: `$(".firstName").on("keypress", function(){` i changed like this but this is not working